# Excel: I would like to graph data from two different sheets against each other

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

So here's what I've got:
Sheet 1:

```
  57    18  76
 194    82  9
 174    88  102
  13    44  133
```

Sheet 2:

```
2081    1126    1365
2867    1053    1381
2707    1984    1623
1084    1726    2050
```

What I'd like to do is have Sheet1:A1 map to Sheet2:A1 and graph them against each other, with Sheet 1 providing the X axis and Sheet 2 providing the Y axis.

Please help.

Comment: So you want A1 (x) to map to A2 (y), and not A1 to A1?  Also, is each column a different series, and are they mapped (e.g. B1 to B1, C1 to C1)?

Comment: Heh , thanks for catching that mistake-edited it in the original post.  Each column is just a year, so they are not really a different series.  I'd basically like to have A1 to A1, A2 to A2, B1 to B1, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Excel's chart data dialogs make this fairly easy to accomplish.

1. Create an XY/Scatter chart.
2. Add your data series:
   Series name:  ="Year 1"
   X Values: =sheet1!A1:A4
   Y Values: =sheet2!A1:A4
3. Add your additional series.
4. Format to taste.

Comment: Would I then be able to have a fitline for the data as a whole, or would it be for each individual series?

Comment: Trendlines are per series, so you'd have 3 in your example.  If it helped, I'd appreciate an upvote.

Comment: I've upvoted you (of course) but those are hidden due to my lack of reputation.  I'm a new account.